# Face API - Variation in # of Emotion Attributes

Tags: android, azure, attributes, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am using the Microsoft Face API to detect faces and emotions in Android. I have a `TreeMap` whose key is the probability of an emotion attribute with the value being the attributes name like so:

```
TreeMap<Double, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();
treeMap.put(person.faceAttributes.emotion.happiness, "Happiness");
treeMap.put(person.faceAttributes.emotion.anger, "Anger");
treeMap.put(person.faceAttributes.emotion.disgust, "Disgust");
treeMap.put(person.faceAttributes.emotion.sadness, "Sadness");
treeMap.put(person.faceAttributes.emotion.neutral, "Neutral");
treeMap.put(person.faceAttributes.emotion.surprise, "Surprise");
treeMap.put(person.faceAttributes.emotion.fear, "Fear");
```

*(person is an object of the type `Face`)*

What I want to do is rank those 7 emotions from most likely to least likely but the problem is that **the size of `treeMap` varies**. For example, when I choose to get the emotion attributes of a face that is **smiling**, `treeMap.size()` returns **2**. When I choose to get the emotion attributes of a face that is mainly **neutral**, `treeMap.size()` returns **3**.

Does anyone know why this behavior is occurring even though I have added 7 key-value pairs to `treeMap` using `treeMap.put()`? I have found that the key-value pairs which *do* exist in `treeMap` are the most likely emotions, but even if the other attributes were to be 0, why aren't they still being added to `treeMap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that this error is occurring is because you are using a `TreeMap` which only allows unique keys. What this means is that if there are more than one emotions with `0.0%` confidence, then only the last one will be stored because the key for your `TreeMap` is a `Double`.

Therefore, with the code that you have posted, you will only receive the emotions that had different percentages of confidence levels. To fix this problem what you should do is switch the types of the `TreeMap` like so:

```
TreeMap<String, Double> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();
```

Now, if you want to sort the `TreeMap` by the values, `Double`, and not the key, you will have to use a `Comparator`. You can find a [good solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values) about how to do that.

Basically what that solution does is take the `Map` passed in, makes a list of the values, sorts the values, and then returns back the sorted `Map`. I hope this answers your question!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Arathi. Although I have already gotten it to work as desired, your detailed answer should help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this was happening was that I was using a `TreeMap` which does not allow duplicate keys. Therefore, if more than one emotion attribute returned 0.0, then only the most recent one would be kept since 0.0 is the key.

Instead, if I had made the `String` the key, *(Such as "Happiness" or "Anger")*, then the `TreeMap` would have contained values for all 7 emotions.